# Using TinyMCE as a text editor

Tags: html, plugins, text, tinymce, textarea

TinyMCE is used in one of my projects as it was meant to be used; a WYSIWYG HTML editor.

I created a number of plug-ins for it that inserts certain fragments of text into the HTML and all is working fine. The plug-ins use TinyMCE's `createMenuButton` to create a menu button and `tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', ...)` to do the inserting.

Now I need to add an editor for plain text in the same project. The text-only editor would also need to be able to insert those same fragments of text into plain `<textarea>` or `<input type="text">` inputs.

Rather than duplicating code, I'd like to re-use the plug-ins written for TinyMCE.

Is there any way to either use TinyMCE as a plain text editor or use just the individual plug-ins?

I'm using TinyMCE 3 and can't upgrade to 4 due to missing essential features.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the editor "as is", but strip the html tags afterwards.